# Date format in angular material works in one page and does not work in another

Tags: angular, angular-material

TS

```
    export const MY_FORMATS = {
      parse: {
        dateInput: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
      },
      display: {
          dateInput: 'DD-MMM-YYYY',
          monthYearLabel: 'MMM',
          dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
          monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
      }
    };
@Component({
  selector: 'app-view-pmodata',
  templateUrl: './view-pmodata.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./view-pmodata.component.css'],
  providers: [
    { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE] },
    { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS }
    ]
})
```

I am having a strange issue,I have the same code cut and pasted in another component and it works fine.

How do I check whether the useValue is using the values ? I have a angular material page where I need to

display date in the format dd-Month(3-char)-yyyy,But it works in one page and does not work,What may be

the reason for this scenario?In the non working page the date format is yyyy-mm-dd.Please help.

Comment: can you add stackblitz for this including both component.

Comment: Hav you tried moving the providers section to your `AppModule`?  If you're using the same date style in multiple places, it would be better to import the `MomentDateModule` there rather than providing services at the component level.  That is the approach they recommend in the Angular Material Documentation (https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#customizing-the-parse-and-display-formats).